# Switch multiple case statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

Can someone suggest me how can I replace the below code?

How do I rewrite the code in order to avoid the repetition of the block `case 3:{code block A; break;}`?

```
switch(i) {
  case 1:  {code block A; break;}

  case 2:  {code block b; break;}

  case 3:  {code block A; break;}

  default: {code block default; break;}
}
```

How can I have combined code for case 1 and case 3?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

This format is shown in the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
        code block A;
        break;
    case 2:
        code block B;
        break;
    default:
        code block default;
        break;
}
```

### EDIT 04/19/2021:

With the release of PHP8 and the new `match` function, it is often a better solution to use `match` instead of `switch`.

For the example above, the equivalent with `match` would be :

```
$matchResult = match($i) {
    1, 3    => // code block A
    2       => // code block B
    default => // code block default
}
```

The `match` statement is shorter, doesn't require breaks and returns a value so you don't have to assign a value multiple times.

Moreover, `match` will act like it was doing a `===` instead of a `==`. This will probably be subject to discussion but it is what it is.

Comment: Yes, this is a standard pattern in almost all languages that supports `switch - case`. It's called  a "fallthrough", as you fall through one case into the next. That's why you have the calls to `break` in there, to prevent it from falling through where you don't want it.

Comment: if i = 1, the php is going to test if i = 3? or is going to go directly to the code?

Comment: @MatheusOliveira I think that when a case is matched, it continues until it reaches a break. So for the above switch example, if $i = 3, code block A is executed, until it reaches the break. If $i = 1, the code is run following case 1:, until it reaches the break. If you wanted to, you could put additional code following case 1, which would only work for case 1, but then if there is no break, code block A will run too.

Answer (score 13):

Something like this

```
switch(i) {
    case 1:
    case 3:  {code block A; break;}

    case 2:  {code block b; break;}

    default: {code block default; break;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
    $i = 10;
    switch($i){
        case $i == 1 || $i > 3:
            echo "working";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "i = 2";
            break;
        default: 
          echo "i = $i";
          break;
    }
```